# Google Analytics - Retrieve Real Time data to a database

Tags: mysql, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have been searching alot in the internet and can't find an answer.
Is it possible to retrieve real time data from GA to let's say MSSQL?
I would like to store these data somewhere so i can reuse them in some other applications to view real time data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the [Real-time Google Analytics API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/v3/) lets you request the data for what is currently happening on your site.  If memory services its basically the last 5 minutes of data that is returned.

There are a few things you should know.

1. the data that you can get is very limited because the data hasn't completed processing. Check [dimensions and metrics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/dimsmets/) reference.
2. The Real Time Reporting API, in limited beta, is available for developer preview only. [Sign up to access the API](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1qfRFysCikpgCMGqgF3yXdUyQW4xAlLyjKuOoOEFN2Uw/viewform).

It normally doesn't take that long to get access and you wont get an email from Google stating you have access.   Just try again the next day if it works you are in.

**Answer to question in comments:**

Before you can request data from a Google API you need to register a project on [Google developer console](https://console.developers.google.com).  Once you have done that you can find the project number on the settings page

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, can you tell me what is "Developer Console Project Number"??

Comment: Its normally 24 hours to get access

Comment: Yes I saw the message from google after i signed up :-)